# Obsolete("somestring", true) attribute when called via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, attributes

I want to mark an empty constructor as [Obsolete("...", true)] because it's for EF Core only and I don't want it to be called. The thing is, I don't know weather this will create problems with EF Core or not (it won't be a compiler error because it is called via reflection, but will reflection work with this attribute?)

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you apply `ObsoleteAttribute` on any method or property, you need to pass the message and **isError**. This will create a compile-time error if IsError is true else it will generate a warning.

```
[ObsoleteAttribute(message, isError)]
```

When you calling this method using reflection, it won't give you an error and successfully executed. please refer to the example below :

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("This method is obsolete. Call NewMethod instead.", true)]
public string OldMethod()
{
    return "You have called OldMethod.";
}
```

Invoke this method using reflection

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Example).GetMethod("OldMethod");
var result = method.Invoke(this, null);
```

It gets executed successfully.

As reflection know the value of IsError, you can play with that in case you want to put restrictions. Reflection

```
MemberInfo[] members = typeof(Class).GetMembers();
foreach (var member in members)
{
    ObsoleteAttribute[] attribs = (ObsoleteAttribute[])member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), false);
    if (attribs.Length > 0)
    {
        ObsoleteAttribute attrib = attribs[0];
        var isErrorValue = attrib.IsError // you can use this.
    }
}
```

**Using EFCore**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(TodoContext).GetMethod("OldMethod");
    if (method != null)
    {
        var result = method.Invoke(null, null);
    }
    return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
}
```

Here DBContext contains obsolete method and it is also working fine.

Comment: But I asked it in broader context. does EF Core does the ```attrib.IsError``` check and dosen't work if its set to true?

Comment: It is also working fine with no errors. There is no validation in EFCore for obsoleted methods. (refer sample code above).